Estimate the amount of RAM that can be allocated
I would like to estimate the amount of allocatable memory in a system. On its outset, the question is very platform-dependent and next to impossible to answer. The concrete use case hopefully makes a sensible answer possible.
Before diving in, I note the possibility of an X-Y-problem. The real question is guessing a sensible parallelism for compiling code.

Practically speaking, I'd like to know how much RAM can be allocated before something equivalent to Linux' out-of-memory killer kicks in. In case of a 32bit environment, the RAM may be distributed to multiple processes to avoid running into address space limits.
The method should work on Linux, but ideally there should be a fallback that also works on GNU/Hurd. An approach that passes both in principle is searching for MemTotal in /proc/meminfo. Other unixoid kernels would be nice, but are less important here.
On Linux, we tend to partition machines into containers. The resources of a container can be partitioned using control groups. For instance setting memory.max on the memory controller of a container cgroup2 would result in the OOM killer to be invoked sooner rather than later.
It is unclear how this would apply to memory ballooning in virtual machines.

Obviously, this can only be a guess and reality will differ. However, coming up with a guess would allow for more efficient resource consumption and avoiding builds getting killed several hours into them.
The baseline is MemTotal in /proc/meminfo. Can we do better?
